# How to count the amount of data in each column in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server that has 490 columns and today I need to add some more. I have an API that populates this table from an external system and currently, it is taking about 16 hours to sync as there are ~550,000 rows in the said table. I need to count the number of rows in use in each column to see if there are anywhere I can remove.

I've looked into this issue for a little time now and resorted to posting here as a last-ditch effort. I have tried a few different ways but nothing is quite hitting what I need. I know I could go through and do COUNT(column_name) but there are 490 columns and this isn't really feasible.

So I am currently using the sys.columns table to get a list of the rows in the said table, and then using an outer apply using COUNT(*) from table. This is kinda working but obviously just returning me the total amount of rows in the table again each row.

I think I need to replace the Count(*) with a COUNT(sys.columns.name) but that doesn't work either, it returns a "Aggregates on the right side of an APPLY cannot reference columns from the left side." error.

The code I feel is currently closest is as follows but I could be a million miles away.

```
 SELECT

  name as 'Column',
  Counter.total   

 FROM sys.columns WITH (NOLOCK)

 OUTER APPLY
 (
    SELECT TOP 1
        COUNT(*) as total
    FROM lead WITH (nolock) 
 ) as Counter

 WHERE sys.columns.object_id = 544720993
```

This throws back the following -

```
Column    |     total
______________________

Column1   |       512345

Column2   |       512345

Column3   |       512345

Column4   |       512345

Column5   |       512345
```

However, in an ideal world, I would like the following

```
Column    |     total
______________________
Column1   |      512345 --(meaning no nulls in this column)

Column2   |      435765 --(mean some nulls in this column)

Column3   |      123423

Column4   |      76 --(meaning only 73 non nulls on this column)

Column5   |      0 --(meaning every row is null in this column)
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Hi RyanJ, I wrote an answer for the question you deleted about adding work hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a cursor with dynamic SQL that inserts each `COUNT` check on a temporary table.

You can control the schema, tables and columns to check with the cursor's `SELECT`.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ColumnResults') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #ColumnResults

CREATE TABLE #ColumnResults (
    SchemaName VARCHAR(100),
    TableName VARCHAR(100),
    ColumnName VARCHAR(100),
    TotalRows INT,
    NotNullAmount INT)


DECLARE @SchemaName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(100)

DECLARE ColumnCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
        QUOTENAME(T.TABLE_SCHEMA),
        QUOTENAME(T.TABLE_NAME),
        QUOTENAME(T.COLUMN_NAME)
    FROM
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS T
    WHERE
        T.TABLE_NAME = 'YourTableName' AND      -- Filter here the table you want to check
        T.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YourTableSchema'      -- Filter here the schema you want to check
    ORDER BY
        T.TABLE_SCHEMA,
        T.TABLE_NAME,
        T.COLUMN_NAME

OPEN ColumnCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM ColumnCursor INTO 
    @SchemaName, 
    @TableName,
    @ColumnName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    DECLARE @DynamicSQL VARCHAR(MAX) = '
        INSERT INTO #ColumnResults (
            SchemaName,
            TableName,
            ColumnName,
            TotalRows,
            NotNullAmount)
        SELECT
            SchemaName = ''' + @SchemaName + ''',
            TableName = ''' + @TableName + ''',
            ColumnName = ''' + @ColumnName + ''',
            TotalRows = COUNT(1),
            NotNullAmount = COUNT(' + @ColumnName + ')
        FROM
            ' + @SchemaName + '.' + @TableName + ' AS T'

    -- PRINT (@DynamicSQL)
    EXEC (@DynamicSQL)

    FETCH NEXT FROM ColumnCursor INTO 
        @SchemaName, 
        @TableName,
        @ColumnName

END

CLOSE ColumnCursor
DEALLOCATE ColumnCursor


SELECT
    C.*
FROM
    #ColumnResults AS C
ORDER BY
    C.SchemaName,
    C.TableName,
    C.ColumnName
```

You can comment the `EXEC` and uncomment the `PRINT` to check for the dynamic SQL created before executing.

Note that this will actually execute one `SELECT` for each column instead of a `SELECT` for all columns in a table. You could tamper the dynamic SQL a little so it works once per table while checking all columns, but I find this approach tidier and capable of working across schemas and tables on the same manner.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is very close to what I need, I appreciate it! I have now realized that the API has made rows actually display blank instead of null, so thats throwing off the results, but I can probably tweak the dynamicSQl to account for this! Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Sample Data

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tp](
    [a] [char](2) NULL,
    [b] [char](2) NULL,
    [c] [char](2) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

GO    
INSERT INTO [Tp] ([a],[b],[c])VALUES('a','a','a')
INSERT INTO [Tp] ([a],[b],[c])VALUES('1','1','1')
INSERT INTO [Tp] ([a],[b],[c])VALUES('2','2','2')
INSERT INTO [Tp] ([a],[b],[c])VALUES(NULL,'9',NULL)
INSERT INTO [Tp] ([a],[b],[c])VALUES('3','3','3')
INSERT INTO [Tp] ([a],[b],[c])VALUES('4','4','4')
INSERT INTO [Tp] ([a],[b],[c])VALUES(NULL,NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO [Tp] ([a],[b],[c])VALUES(NULL,'7',NULL)
INSERT INTO [Tp] ([a],[b],[c])VALUES(NULL,NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO [Tp] ([a],[b],[c])VALUES('8','8','8')
INSERT INTO [Tp] ([a],[b],[c])VALUES('9','9','9')
INSERT INTO [Tp] ([a],[b],[c])VALUES(NULL,NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO [Tp] ([a],[b],[c])VALUES('','','')
INSERT INTO [Tp] ([a],[b],[c])VALUES('','','')
INSERT INTO [Tp] ([a],[b],[c])VALUES('','5','')
INSERT INTO [Tp] ([a],[b],[c])VALUES('2','','')
SELECT * FROM [Tp]
```

Dynamic Sql script to get the expected result

```
 DECLARE @ColumnCount nvarchar(max),
         @Sql nvarchar(max)

SELECT @Sql = STUFF((SELECT ' UNION ALL '+ ' '+'SELECT '''+TABLE_NAME+''' AS TABLE_NAME,'+''''+COLUMN_NAME+''''+' AS ColumName'+',SUM(CASE WHEN '+COLUMN_NAME+' IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As Countof_nulls
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN ISNULL(NULLIF('+COLUMN_NAME+',''''),''1'')=''1'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As CountOf_EmptySpace
      ,COUNT('+COLUMN_NAME+') As Count_not_nulls 
     FROM '+TABLE_NAME  
FROM 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME ='Tp' --Enter your table in the query
FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,10,'')

EXEC (@Sql)
```

Result

```
TABLE_NAME  ColumName   Countof_nulls   CountOf_EmptySpace  Count_not_nulls
***************************************************************************
    Tp          a           5                   9               11
    Tp          b           3                   7               13
    Tp          c           5                   10              11
```

Comment: Bro, there are 490 columns, he cant write this on each right?

Comment: bro then it required dynamic sql, ivl write the code and let him know